# Android: why the ICICI iMobile Pay App shows the "rooted/jailbroken" device with my app?

Tags: android

[image]

After installed my App, the ICICI iMobile Pay app shows the above dialog.
Finally I found the root cause, because I used the "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1" library.
That lib introduces the following service

```
        <service
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService"
        android:directBootAware="false"
        android:enabled="@bool/enable_system_job_service_default"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        tools:targetApi="n" />
```

enable_system_job_service_default is true if android 6 or higher. If I set the enabled to false, then the ICICI iMobile Pay goes fine.

Why the ICICI iMobile Pay detects such BIND_JOB_SERVICE jobservice? Is it a bug of the ICICI App? It's really annoying

Comment: What is the ICICI iMobile Pay app?

Comment: Check whether you enabled `developer option`. If you disable  developer option it might work @MarianPaździoch

Comment: Found the root cause. It's a false positive detection of the bank app. However, they need more time to fix it, as ICICI app is not the only one that gets affected for many of them use the same RASP sulution, and they need time for the users to upgrade the bank Apps:(

Comment: Still - WTF is ICICI app?

Comment: @Marian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICICI_Bank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the root cause. It's a false positive detection of the bank app.
However, they need more time to fix it, as ICICI app is not the only one that gets affected for many of them use the same RASP sulution, and they need time for the users to upgrade the bank Apps:(

Comment: I mailed their support, their support did-not understand the problem :(

Comment: https://support.onespan.com/csm?sys_kb_id=95fdc7ac87a915100507206e8bbb35ee&id=kb_article_view&sysparm_rank=1&sysparm_tsqueryId=7406fffc1be95510231d7739cd4bcbb5

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's a bug i suppose , icici bank should update app , am too getting it but my device is non rooted

Comment: yes, it's said the RASP false positive detection issue..